# Error running Default: This configuration cannot be debugged

Tags: .net-core, rider

How to enable debug in Rider from JetBrains for .net core project.
When I press debug it show 
Error running Default: This configuration cannot be debugged.
Anyone knows what config I need to create or what I need to do in order to debug .net core web api hello world project

Answer (score 0):

.Net core debugger isn't supported yet. But it's coming soon

Comment: Thanks. Rider looks really promising. Really looking forward

Comment: @Artem Bukhonov - could you please update this question / answer when the rider build does support it? Thanks.

Comment: @Charlino Debugger seems to be working fine for .NET SDK 1.0.4 in v2017.1